# Nested populate with Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

So I'm trying to populate already populated documents:

```
postModel
    .findOne({
        _id: postId
    }).select()
    .populate('author')
    .populate('sharedBy')
    .populate('replies')
    .exec(function(err, post) {
        if (err) return err;
```

However, the `replies` array will hold a bunch of Posts which have `author` and `sharedBy` keys that I also need to populate. This is my strategy:

```
    .populate('author')
    .populate('sharedBy')
    .populate('replies')
    .exec(function(err, post) {
        if (err) return err;
        post.deepPopulate(function(err, post){
```

And `deepPopulate`:

```
PostSchema.method('deepPopulate', function(cb) {
    var post = this;
    async.map(this.replies, function(reply, done) {
        mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema).findOne({
            _id: reply._id
        }).select().populate('author').populate('sharedBy').exec(done);
    }, function(err, replies) {
        post.replies = replies;
        cb(err, post);
    });
});
```

It finds the `replies` fine but I can't seem to put them back into the original post that was passed in! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post is a [Mongoose Document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document-js), which means that you can't overwrite properties like you have there. The quick solution is to call [`.toObject`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) on the post, and then overwrite replies.

```
var postObj = post.toObject()
postObj.replies = replies;
cb(err, postObj);
```

`toObject` turns the Mongoose document into a regular object so you can overwrite its properties. The negative here is that, from then on, you can't use Mongoose methods on the post.

I can't help thinking there's a better way to do this.